# Cannot open NVIDIA Visual Profiler on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, cuda

I've installed CUDA kit via `apt-get` following [CUDA installation documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html). However, when I attempt to open NVIDIA Visual Profiler, I can't open it. By the log file I suppose it has something to do with Eclipse but I don't know how to solve it.

#### PC info

- CUDA version: 11.1
- OS Release: Ubuntu focal (20.04.1)
- My GPU is CUDA capable (already checked)

#### Log File

```
!SESSION 2020-12-07 10:24:36.991 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=11.0.9.1
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.633
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.nvidia.pgprof.application 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.637
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.pgprof.application [10]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.viper
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.viper [12]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
              com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.641
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper.application 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.644
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper.application [13]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.viper [12]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
              com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper.birt 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.647
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper.birt [14]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.652
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.ui 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:37.655
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper.application 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.980
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper.application [13]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.viper [12]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
              com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.ui 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.980
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.980
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.981
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.981
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.core.filesystem.java7 [84]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
  Unresolved requirement: Fragment-Host: org.eclipse.core.filesystem; bundle-version="[1.4.100,2.0.0)"


!ENTRY com.nvidia.pgprof.application 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.981
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.pgprof.application [10]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.viper
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.viper; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
       com.nvidia.viper [12]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor; bundle-version="11.1.0.202010130340"; singleton:="true"
              com.nvidia.cuda.ide.editor [6]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="[5.8.0.nvidia,5.8.1)"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.ui; bundle-version="5.8.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.cdt.ui [71]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="[5.2.0,6.0.0)"
                         -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.cdt.core; bundle-version="5.7.0.nvidia-qualifier"; singleton:="true"
                            org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
                              Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY com.nvidia.viper.birt 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.982
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: com.nvidia.viper.birt [14]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 2 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.982
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cdt.core [69]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2020-12-07 10:24:38.982
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "com.nvidia.viper.application.application" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.ReportExecutor, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application, org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.GenTopic, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Looks like the code may be too old to run with Java 11, try Java 8

Answer (score 2):

As @greg-449 commented, I just had to change Java version:

```
sudo update-altenatives --config java
# chose java8
```